Fix "bundle initial exceeded maximum budget" warning in an NX monorepo library (library, not app)
I have created a NX monorepo workspace in which I have a nx.json file and a project.json for each library in the libs folder. Since I used the latest version of NX (@nx/angular@19.4.4) I don't have any workspace.json nor angular.json file in my workspace.
When I try to build the whole project I get the following warnings:
Warning: /<my-workspace>/libs/layout/src/lib/components/panel/panel.component.scss exceeded maximum budget. Budget 2.05 kB was not met by 1.55 kB with a total of 3.60 kB.

Warning: /<my-workspace>/libs/messenger/src/lib/components/messages-viewer/messages-viewer.component.scss exceeded maximum budget. Budget 2.05 kB was not met by 122 bytes with a total of 2.17 kB.

Warning: bundle initial exceeded maximum budget. Budget 512.00 kB was not met by 938.53 kB with a total of 1.45 MB.

As far as I know I should add settings like the following to the project.json file of the library that triggered the warning
{
  "budgets": [
    {
      "type": "initial",
      "maximumWarning": "1mb",
      "maximumError": "2mb"
    }
  ]
}

In this way:
{
  "targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@nx/angular:package",
      "outputs": ["{workspaceRoot}/dist/{projectRoot}"],
      "options": {
        "project": "libs/messenger/ng-package.json"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "tsConfig": "libs/messenger/tsconfig.lib.prod.json",
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "1mb",
              "maximumError": "2mb"
            }
          ]
        },
        "development": {
          "tsConfig": "libs/messenger/tsconfig.lib.json"
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "production"
    }
  }
}

But if I do that I get the following error:
NX   'budgets' is not found in schema

Instead having the same property in the project.json of any app (not library) of the same monorepo workspace doesn't throw the error above.
Why??? What does it mean?

You can't set budgets to build a library because the @nx/angular:package executor doesn't allow to. Checkout the configurations you can specify when using that executor: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/blob/19.4.4/packages/angular/src/executors/package/schema.json#L19-L42 Is the error raised if only building the library? Maybe those budgets can be only set for application projects. I don't use nx though, so not sure about configuring budgets in there (just done that in Angular CLI based projects)

Uhm, your hint make me to see that for apps the build executor is @angular-devkit/build-angular:browser, instead for the libraries is @nx/angular:package.  Do you know is it's right, what's the difference and if I can change it?

Angular CLI uses that builder for Angular apps created before v17. For libraries built with Angular CLI, the builder is: @angular-devkit/build-angular:ng-packagr. That builder doesn't have support for buckets either: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/18.1.2/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/builders/ng-packagr/schema.json#L6-L24. Seems the @nx/angular:package uses that same one under the hood: https://nx.dev/nx-api/angular/executors/package You can try using the Angular CLI one at cost of dropping incremental build support. But doesn't seem the source of the issue

Btw it is weird that you're using @angular-devkit/build-angular:browser instead of the Nx equivalent of https://nx.dev/nx-api/angular/executors/webpack-browser btw You're not getting the incremental builds support. Anyway haven't used nx so not an expert if that incremental builds support may come with issues too
